# Why is $\frac{1}{W}$ not a valid Ito integrand?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion. Why is $\xi = \frac{1}{W}$ not a valid Ito integrand?

Here is what seems to be an indirect argument. Suppose it is. Then
$$
dW = W \xi dW.
$$
So that
$$
W_t = e^{\int_0^t \xi' dW_s - \frac12 \int_0^t |\xi'|^2 ds} > 0, \;\; 
$$
which is impossible. Is there a more direct argument using properties of Brownian paths?

The reciprocal normal distribution has no finite moments but why is localization not possible?

Comment: Localization allows you to cut away big times... but here you would need to cut out small times to make the integrand integrable (because $\xi$ has a singularity at $t=0$).